# Image upload working only with manual made folders php

Tags: php, directory, image-uploading, mkdir

I'm creating a website for someone and I'm creating a way for him to upload images to his sites different projects.
The projects works the way that all files in /includes/prosjekter/*projectnamehere*/img gets displayed on the page. So i need to upload files to that path.

When i create the path manually on my local machine and try to upload an image to that project it works great.

However if a create the project path and files with the website and this code it doesn't work at all.

```
if(isset($_POST['nyttProj']) && $admin){
    $name = $_POST['overskrift'];
    $beskNew = $_POST['beskFromTxt'];
    $path = "includes/prosjekter/".$name."/";
    mkdir($path,0777);
    mkdir($path.'/img',0777);
    $fileTxt = fopen($path.'besk.php','w',1);
    fwrite($fileTxt, $beskNew);
    fclose($fileTxt);
}
```

I'm guessing something is wrong with the folders considering it works perfectly with manually made folders.

Anyone know whats going on and maybe have a solution?

Comment: What error message(s) do you receive? And why are you creating a `.php` file in a folder that is supposed to hold _images_? Am I missing something?

Comment: always is good when creating folders to use absolute paths. In your case check permissions for parent folders

Comment: Well, no errormessages at the moment, but if i remove the isset($_FILES['file']) check i have in the image upload i get a "Notice: Undefined index: file".

The .php file isn't in the folder thats supposed to hold images, but in it's parent, and is for a description of the project, no reason really why it's a .php file and not a .txt file.

Comment: In this case it seems that your problem relies on your post. For some reason your file is not being posted. Make sure that your form has this attribute: enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: It already has that attribute and i'm not sure how it can be that when the exact same form works if i create the folder manually in windows.

Comment: Are you testing both situations on the same server?

Comment: All is done on a local wampserver on my windows 7 machine. There is nothing different, other than the folders being created with a right click "new folder" in the projects folder vs. mkdir();

Comment: Couldn't figure this one out so i ended up rewriting the rest of the code to add project names to each imagefile and have a imagefolder for all project images instead.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Make sure that your webserver process user has the right permissions on folder you are trying to create sub-folder. If you are using apache, then apache user has to have these permissions.

Second, you have to create each sub-folder separately. So you have to create "includes", then "prosjekter" and so on...

Comment: Sorry, actually you can create nested folders, but you have to set the third parameter of mkdir to true, like this mkdir($path,0777, true);

Comment: Either way the includes/prosjekter/ folder is already created so I am creating the folder separately.

How would i find out if apache has the right permissions?
Currently using wampserver as a local webserver on windows 7 before the guy purchases an online webhost.

Comment: If you are starting apache manually, then it uses your user. If you are starting via services then it uses the system user. In both cases you would already have the right permissions. Very weird your issue.